# v-html directive renders raw html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, storybook

Here is how my component looks like

```
<template>
 <div v-html="someHtml"></div>
</template>

 <script>
 export default {
   name: "test",
   props: {
    someHtml: String,
   },
 }
 </script>
```

The way component is being used in storybooks:

```
export const testtest = () => ({
  components: {test},
  props: {
    someHtml: {default: text('somehtml', '<a href="link" class="link text-theme">see data</a>')}
},
template: `
    <test v-bind="$props"/>
`,
});
```

Output is always html raw string like this ==>

```
<a href="link" class="link text-theme">see data</a>
```

Docs are clear about the usage, and still it is not working for me.

I am passing raw html as a prop. When I am using raw html from vue js data, then it is working and is able to "parse" html string and renders it properly.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible fiddle for this. Work fine with a prop, see this fiddle [with props for v-html](https://jsfiddle.net/26Lpczxb/1/)

Comment: @ambianBeing check the accepted answer, it is a storybook issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a problem with `v-html`, but caused by storybook - [the `text` knob escapes HTML](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/3722).

There is a way to turn this off though, by setting [`escapeHTML` to `false` for the knobs addon](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/3722#issuecomment-395993304).

Answer (score 2):

#### [ Solution ]

To render a v-html follow the steps.
1.Your template should look like this

```
<template>
  <div v-html='someText'></div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
 export default {
   name: "test",
   props: {
    someHtml: String,
   },
   data(){
       return{
         someText: this.props.someHTML,
       }
     }   
 }
 </script>
```

this should work fine. HTML codes should be defined in the data object in-order to render in V-html on Vuejs

Comment: Thanks for comment, I know this will work, but my html is coming from the prop. So I have to use prop not data.

Comment: Answer Modified. Check it you can also assign props to render V-html @NikolaMitic. Vote up if it is works according to your need

Comment: Problem was in the html string itself, because of storybook bug, please see the accepted answer. Thanks for the help!